# how to recursively loop this?

Tags: php

Now I have

```
Array(1 => Array("aaa","bbb","ccc"))
Array(2 => Array("eee","fff","ggg","hhh"))
```

And I want to make a String

```
$a = "ST_Union(ST_Union('aaa','bbb'),'ccc')" 
$b = "ST_Union(ST_Union(ST_Union('eee','fff'),'ggg'),'hhh')"
```

How could I done this in PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**: updated solution a little, now much more simple and readable:

http://ideone.com/tdIXT

```
function wrapWithUnion(array $params)
{
    if (is_null($params[0])) {
        return "'{$params[1]}'";
    }

    return "ST_Union({$params[0]},'{$params[1]}')";
}

$arr = array("eee","fff","ggg","hhh");

$result = null;

foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $result = wrapWithUnion(array($result, $val));
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you could use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function, which will join the elements of the array into a string, separated by the "glue" of your choice.

Example:

```
$arr1 = Array("aaa","bbb","ccc");

$str1 = implode(",",$arr1);
//aaa,bbb,ccc

$str2 = implode($arr1);
//aaabbbccc
```

Comment: I just want to see some PHP code example for this case, btw thanks for a key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function wrapWithUnion($input)
{
    $template = 'ST_Union(%1$s, %2$s)';
    $output = "'" . array_shift($input) . "'";
    while ($item = array_shift($input))
    {
        $output = sprintf($template, $output, "'" . $item . "'");
    }

    return $output;
}
```

But what do you want to do if the input array has less than 2 items in it? This function may not handle those cases as you would hope.

Comment: Meaning that you would never perform these actions on such an array in the first place? In that case, this function should work for you. Sorry, it does not use recursion.